# php replace from multidimensional array

Tags: php

I was looking for a way in php which can replace a string like this

```
<?php
$ar = array(
"ToFind" => "ToBeReplaced",
"ToFind1" => "ToBeReplaced1"
);
?>
```

and so on ?

Any help ?
Thanks

Comment: This array is not multi-dimensional, BTW.

Comment: I think you mean associative array, not multi-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple replacement tasks can be done like this using `str_replace`:

```
$string = str_replace(array_keys($ar), array_values($ar), $string);
```

As noted in the examples, this may sometimes lead to unexpected behaviour because the replacement is performed left-to-right, ie. the output of the first replacement acts as input for the second replacement and so on. The comments on the [PHP manual page for `str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) contain a lot of ideas for replacing occurrences in the original string. [This one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#88569), for example, might be close to what you're looking for:

```
function stro_replace($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    return strtr($subject, array_combine($search, $replace));
}

$search = array('ERICA', 'AMERICA');
$replace = array('JON', 'PHP');
$subject = 'MIKE AND ERICA LIKE AMERICA';

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
// output: "MIKE AND JON LIKE AMJON", which is not correct

echo stro_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
// output: "MIKE AND JON LIKE PHP", which is correct
```

Comment: It replaces from left to right doesnt it ? What i want is just to replace all the matches in the string

Comment: Nope, this will replace all the matches in the string.

Comment: @kritya Yes, it replaces from left to right. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ill try it when i get to home

Answer (score 2):

```
$ar = array("ToFind" => "ToBeReplaced", "ToFind1" => "ToBeReplaced1");
echo str_replace(array_keys($ar), $ar, $subject);
```

http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: It replaces from left to right doesnt it ?
What i want is just to replace all the matches in the string

Comment: @kritya: What do you mean by *It replaces from left to right* ? It should replace all occurrences. Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: No take a better look at the documentation